# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$ if $f(x)=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$,$\frac{1}{2^n} < x \leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}, f(0)=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$ if $f(x)=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$,$\frac{1}{2^n} < x \leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}},x \in [0,1], n \in N$ and $f(0)=0$

My solution:

$$\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{\frac{1}{2^n}}^{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}} f(x)dx$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{\frac{1}{2^n}}^{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}} \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}dx$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}$$

$$=\frac{1/2}{1-1/4} $$

$$=\frac{2}{3}$$.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct question?

Comment: @Tavish This is exactly how it is given

Comment: The solution you give assumes that the integral exists. +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The integral exists because the function is a stair function.

Comment: @EDX: I think you mean it is step function. However note that step function involves finite number of subintervals where the function is constant. Here the situation is a bit different. The existence of integral (Riemann sense) follows by noting that function is monotone, or by noting that the discontinuities form an infinite set with finite number of limit points (actually one limit point here).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I understand the definition of his function by $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}}1_{   [\frac{1}{2^n}  ; \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} ] }(x) $ which is integrable. So this is a step function but much more than this, because null outside the center one.